# Post an array of strings within a state object from React to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose userSchema like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 32
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: 32
  },
  hashed_password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
skills: {
     type: Array,
     default: [],
     required: true
   }
}, {timestamps: true});
```

The `skills` field is an array. Ideally, I would like to render a text input dynamically on user input so that users may enter any number of skills.

With the skills entered into each separate text input, I want to concatenate each of them to a single array to be sent to the db with a POST request.

How can I do this?

Here is my code without the array input:

**Post Request**

```
const signup = (user) => {
    fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user)
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  };

const clickSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    signup({name, email, password, studying});
  };
```

**React DOM without the dynamic `skills` input**

```
const signUpForm = () => (
    <form>
        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Name</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('name')} type="text" className ="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Email</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('email')} type="email" className ="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Password</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('password')} type="password" className="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
            <label className="text-muted">Studying</label>
            <input onChange={handleChange('studying')} type="text" className ="form-control" />
        </div>

        <button onClick={clickSubmit} className="btn btn-primary">
          Sign Up
        </button>
    </form>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your model by the following way

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 32
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    unique: 32
  },
  hashed_password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
skills: {[
    //add the field you want , For example :- `in : {type: String , default: null}`
    required: true
   ]}
}, {timestamps: true});
```

This will help you to solve your problem .